# Unable to Access Let's Encrypt Certificates in Docker Container

Tags: node.js, docker, ssl, lets-encrypt

I'm having trouble accessing Let's Encrypt certificates (using certbot) inside a Docker container (running on an Ubuntu droplet on digital ocean).

I've set up a Node.js application that requires SSL/TLS certificates for HTTPS communication. The certificates are generated using Certbot and are stored in `/etc/letsencrypt/live/companyexample.com/` on the host machine.

I've tried various approaches to make the certificates accessible to my Docker container, but none of them have worked so far. Here's what I've tried:

**Bind Mounting the Live Directory:**

```
Docker Run Command: docker run --name example_container -p 3000:3000 -v /etc/letsencrypt/live:/etc/letsencrypt/live -e NODE_ENV=production -d example_server_docker
```

*Result:* The container starts, but my Node.js application throws an error saying it can't find the certificates.

```
root@ubuntu-example-server:~# docker logs example_container
node:internal/fs/utils:347
    throw err;
    ^

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem'
    at Object.openSync (node:fs:601:3)
    at Object.readFileSync (node:fs:469:35)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/index.js:21:11)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1254:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1308:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1117:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:958:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47 {
  errno: -2,
  syscall: 'open',
  code: 'ENOENT',
  path: '/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem'
}
```

**Bind Mounting the Archive Directory:**

```
Docker Run Command: docker run --name example_container -p 3000:3000 -v /etc/letsencrypt/archive:/etc/letsencrypt/archive -e NODE_ENV=production -d example_docker
```

*Result:* Same as the previous approach, the application can't find the certificates.

**Directly Mounting the Certificates:**

```
Docker Run Command: docker run --name example_container -p 3000:3000 -v /etc/letsencrypt/archive/example.com:/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com -e NODE_ENV=production -d example_docker
```

*Result:* Still no luck, the application throws the same error.

**Creating Symbolic Links Inside the Container:**

```
Docker Run Command: docker run --name example_container -p 3000:3000 -v /etc/letsencrypt/live:/certs/live -e NODE_ENV=production -d example_docker

Inside the Container: ln -s /certs/live/example.com/privkey.pem /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem and ln -s /certs/live/example.com/fullchain.pem /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem
```

*Result:* The application still fails to find the certificates.

I've checked the permissions and ownership of the certificate files, and they seem to be correct (owned by root with read-only permissions for owner). I've also verified that the certificates are valid and accessible from the host machine using OpenSSL commands.

```
root@ubuntu-server:~# ls -l /etc/letsencrypt/archive/example.com/privkey1.pem
-rw------- 1 root root 1704 Jul  6 10:46 /etc/letsencrypt/archive/example.com/privkey1.pem
```

and

```
root@ubuntu-server:~# ls -l /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 49 Jul  6 10:46 /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem -> ../../archive/example/privkey1.pem
root@ubuntu-server:~#
```

I also am pretty sure my docker container has root permissions:

```
root@ubuntu-server:~/example/server# ps aux | grep dockerd
root       11358  0.1  4.6 1400224 45960 ?       Ssl  09:43   0:19 dockerd --group docker --exec-root=/run/snap.docker --data-root=/var/snap/docker/common/var-lib-docker --pidfile=/run/snap.docker/docker.pid --config-file=/var/snap/docker/2893/config/daemon.json
```

and here to show the certificate definitely exists:

```
root@ubuntu-server:~/example/server# openssl rsa -in /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem -check
RSA key ok
writing RSA key
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
key details
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
root@ubuntu-server:~/example/server#
```

I'm running out of ideas on how to resolve this issue. Any suggestions or insights would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!